# Subsets of a data frame where certain columns satisfy a condition

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset `catalog` with 3 columns: product id, brand name and product class.

```
import pandas as pd
catalog = {'product_id': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6],
        'brand_name': ['FW', 'GW', 'FK','FW','GW','WU','FK','MU', 'AS'],
        'product_class': ['ACCESSORIES', 'DRINK', 'FOOD', 'ACCESSORIES', 'DRINK', 'FURNITURE','FOOD', 'ELECTRONICS', 'APPAREL']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=catalog)
```

Assume I have a list of product id `prod = [1,3,4].` Now, with Python, I want to list all the brand names corresponding to this list `prod` based on the product_id. How can I do this using only `groupby()` and  `get_group()` functions? I can do this using `pd.DataFrame()` combined with the `zip()` function, but it is too inefficient, as I would need to obtain each column individually.

**Expected output (in dataframe)**

```
Product_id      Brand_name
1               'FW'
3               'FK'
4               'WU'
```

Can anyone give some help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas functions `isin()` and `drop_duplicates()` to achieve this:

```
prod = [1,3,4]
print(df[df.product_id.isin(prod)][["product_id", "brand_name"]].drop_duplicates())
```

Output:

```
   product_id brand_name
0           1         FW
2           3         FK
5           4         WU
```